# How to check if an item already exists in a Room Database?

Tags: android, adapter, android-room, onclicklistener

I have this adapter with a button that dependent on if a object already exists in my Room Database or not will have a differente behavior when it´s clicked. Basically  what I want to do is  if the object exists I want to remove it. In case it doesn´t I want to add it to my database. I created this method in Dao and a Task to   check the existence. Since the Task is asynchronous ,how can I do the verification?

### My Adapter

```
public class RestaurantAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurantAdapter.RestaurantViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Restaurant_> mRestaurants;
    private Activity act;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUserId;
    private View rView;

    public RestaurantAdapter(Context context, List<Restaurant_> restaurants, Activity activity) {
        mRestaurants = restaurants;
        mContext = context;
        act = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public RestaurantViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Get layout inflater from context
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate layout
        rView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_restaurant, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        return new RestaurantViewHolder(rView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RestaurantViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        // Get the data model based on position
        final Activity activity = act;

        final Restaurant_ restaurant = mRestaurants.get(position);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        final TextView name = viewHolder.nameTextView;
        name.setText(restaurant.getName());

        final TextView rating = viewHolder.ratingTextView;
        rating.setText((restaurant.getUserRating().getAggregateRating()));

        final TextView distance = viewHolder.distanceTextView;
        distance.setText(String.valueOf(restaurant.getDistance()) + " Km");

        final ImageButton addToWishlistButton = viewHolder.addToWishlistButton;
        addToWishlistButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Wishlist wishlist = new Wishlist(currentUserId, restaurant.getId());
                //if(alreadyExists){
                //RemoveWLTask rlt=new RemoveWLTask(wishlist,activity);
                //rlt.execute()
               // }

               // else{
                    AddWLTask wlt = new AddWLTask(wishlist, activity);
                    wlt.execute();
                //}
            }
        });

        final ImageButton addToFavoritesButton = viewHolder.addToFavoritesButton;
        addToFavoritesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addToFavoritesButton.getBackground().setTint(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                addToFavorites();
            }
        });

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LiveFragment.getListener().onRestaurantClicked(restaurant.getId());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mRestaurants.size();
    }


    public class RestaurantViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView nameTextView;
        public TextView ratingTextView;
        public TextView distanceTextView;
        public ImageButton addToWishlistButton;
        public ImageButton addToFavoritesButton;

        public RestaurantViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantName);
            ratingTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantRating);
            distanceTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurantDistance);
            addToWishlistButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_wishlist);
            addToFavoritesButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_favorites);
        }

    }

}
```

### My DAO

```
@Dao
public interface DAO {
    @Insert
    public void addToWishlist(Wishlist wishlist);

    @Delete
    public void deleteFromWishlist(Wishlist wishlist);

    @Query("Select restaurantId From wishlist Where userId=:id")
    public String[] loadWishlist(String id);

    @Query("Select restaurantId From wishlist where userId=:userID AND restaurantId=:restaurantID")
    public String[]checkExists(String userID, String restaurantID);
    
}
```

##My Task ##

```
public class CheckWLTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private DB db;
    private Activity activity;
    private String userId;
    private String restaurantId;
    private String [] response;

    public CheckWLTask(Activity activity, String idUser, String idRestaurant) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.userId = idUser;
        this.restaurantId = idRestaurant;
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(activity.getApplicationContext(), DB.class, "sample-db").build();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        while (!isCancelled()) {
            this.response=db.daoAcess().checkExists(userId,restaurantId);
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }


}
``
```

Comment: The easiest solution would probably be to write a Kotlin function that uses coroutines for first asynchronously getting the items from your db and then executing removing/adding operation. It is simple to write in kotlin and can then be called from your java code

Comment: It´s for a university project. I am not sure I can use Kotlin

Comment: did they mention as a strict requirement it has to be java? If not, I would suggest to just give it a try.  It will be much more convenient then trying to sync async tasks

Comment: check it with `select count(restaurantID) from database where restaurantID =: restaurantID` if result == 0, it doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

Place below code in you Dao class:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE value = :value")
int isDataExist(String value)
```

It will return 0 or 1

- 0 if the value is not present in database.
- 1 if the value is present in database